# How to install pydelicious?

Tags: python

Im using on my windows python 3.3.2 I have a problem to instal pydelicious API. I was trying to make it work for a whole week but I couldnt make it happen.
This is my problem:

```
C:\Users\bartl\Desktop\python-delicious-master>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pydelicious
  File "C:\Users\bartl\Desktop\python-delicious-master\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 171
    raise DeliciousItemExistsError, params['url']
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `__init__.py` in the `python-delicious-master/pydelicious/`.
Here is the link for `__init__.py`, https://github.com/pcao10/pydelicious/issues/43
It works for me!